# Deploying Mirror API project to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have been trying to deploy the Mirror API quickstart project for Java that Google provides onto Google App Engine using Maven.
I downloaded the code from github(https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java) and changed the client ID and secret in the **oauth.properties** file.

I succeeded in making it work on localhost, by simple command

> mvn jetty:run

However, I am now having problems deploying it on Google App Engine.
I added **appengine-web.xml** in **src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\** with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>mirror-api-java-test1</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Then, I made a war file with the command

> mvn war:war

and tried to deploy with the follwing command

> appcfg.cmd update \target\glass-java-starter-0.1-SNAPSHOT

I get the following errors when I try it.

```
C:\Users\MCS\Desktop\mirror-quickstart-java-master>appcfg.cmd update target\glass-java-starter-0.1-SNAPSHOT
Reading application configuration data...
5월 14, 2014 6:10:56 오후 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
정보: Successfully processed target/glass-java-starter-0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
5월 14, 2014 6:10:56 오후 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
정보: Successfully processed target/glass-java-starter-0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/web.xml


Beginning interaction for module default...
Email: mcs8779@gmail.com
Password for mcs8779@gmail.com:
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\MCS\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg9012404692012972997.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.
5월 14, 2014 6:11:12 오후 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader getTopLevelNode
심각: Received IOException parsing the input stream for C:\Users\MCS\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg9012404692012972997.tmp\WEB-INF/web.xml
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: invalid byte 3 of 3-byte utf-8 sequence.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:687)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:435)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1753)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanLiteral(XMLEntityScanner.java:1074)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:996)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:438)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:254)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:604)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3122)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:230)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader.getTopLevelNode(AbstractConfigXmlReader.java:207)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader.parse(AbstractConfigXmlReader.java:229)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.processXml(WebXmlReader.java:160)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.processXml(WebXmlReader.java:20)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader.readConfigXml(AbstractConfigXmlReader.java:112)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.readWebXml(WebXmlReader.java:87)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:804)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:615)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:471)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1347)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:332)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:213)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:124)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:120)

5월 14, 2014 6:11:12 오후 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
심각: Received exception processing C:\Users\MCS\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg9012404692012972997.tmp\WEB-INF/web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Received IOException parsing the input stream for C:\Users\MCS\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg9012404692012972997.tmpWEBINF/web.xml
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader.getTopLevelNode(AbstractConfigXmlReader.java:211)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader.parse(AbstractConfigXmlReader.java:229)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.processXml(WebXmlReader.java:160)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.processXml(WebXmlReader.java:20)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader.readConfigXml(AbstractConfigXmlReader.java:112)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.readWebXml(WebXmlReader.java:87)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:804)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:615)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:471)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1347)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:332)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:213)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:124)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:120)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: invalid byte 3 of 3-byte utf-8 sequence.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:687)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:435)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1753)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanLiteral(XMLEntityScanner.java:1074)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:996)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:438)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:254)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:604)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3122)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:230)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader.getTopLevelNode(AbstractConfigXmlReader.java:207)
        ... 14 more


Error Details:
5월 14, 2014 6:11:11 오후 org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
정보: Built File: \index.jsp


com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Received IOException parsing the input stream for C:\Users\MCS\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg9012404692012972997.tmp\WEB-INF/web.xml
Unable to update app: Received IOException parsing the input stream for C:\Users\MCS\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg9012404692012972997.tmp\WEB-INF/web.xml
Please see the logs [C:\Users\MCS\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg1078372849724416694.log] for further information.
```

Please help me out!
(I use Korean version of Windows, so some characters may look weird in the error log)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the error you're getting, it appears there was some kind of encoding error in one of the bytes in the app's web.xml file. My best guess is that this came from a stray edit you made with your Korean keyboard. Though Korean is probably UTF-8 encoded just like any other language, there is plenty of [precedent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920758/malformedbytesequenceexception-invalid-byte-2-of-2-byte-utf-8-sequence) for non-ASCII characters causing the same error.

I would just try replacing your current web.xml file with [a fresh copy](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) from github and recompiling the project.

If that doesn't work, do some research into MalformedByteSequenceException errors and how to fix them. Seems like most people find a way to identify the errant character and delete it, or otherwise find a means to re-encode the file wholesale to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't solve the problem.
Instead, I have turned to using Eclipse with plugins.

Comment: @Myung-chulSung Hoy did you do it using Eclipse plugins, because it keeps telling me not App Engine Project