# Where is Jenkins slave-agent.jnlp with bad UTF-8 so I can fix it

Tags: xml, jenkins

On a Windows 10 system, I can connect my Jenkins slave through the command line but not via Services.

jenkins-slave.err.log shows `MalformedByteSequence: invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence`
[MalformedByteSequenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920758/malformedbytesequenceexception-invalid-byte-2-of-2-byte-utf-8-sequence) explained why it happens (and saved me the headache of transcribing the traceback stack!), but not how to find where the problem is so that I can fix it.

In a browser, I entered http://my-jenkins-master:8080/computer/my_agent/slave-agent.jnlp
Got the dialog window `You have chose to open slave-agent.jnlp` with size 377 bytes
But when I select "Save File" -- nothing happens, and jenkins-slave.err.log shows `Content is not allowed in prolog`

Other agents can download their slave-agent.jnlp OK, so I don't know where the problem is so that I can fix it.

Will be glad to supply any other information you need.

Comment: You don't really need to download `slave-agent.jnlp`. I recommend to install the service through the command-line using `jenkins-slave.exe`. It is not difficult, see [this tutorial](https://hayato-iriumi.net/2019/05/23/how-to-install-jenkins-slave-as-windows-service/). In addition it allows you to automate slave setup.

Comment: The whole Jenkins thing had been already set up before I inherited. Somehow this one item got broken and I'd like to fix it. Where is the file (presumably on the Jenkins master) so I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

The error message comes from a wrong combination of the `jnlpUrl` and `secret` parameters. E.g. jnlpUrl from build-node-01 and secret from an other build-node.

Check your script where you connect the agent (build-node) to your jenkins.

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://your-jenkins.com/computer/your-build-node-ABC/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret <secret for your build node DEF>
```

Make sure the `jnlpUrl`and `secret` are for the same agent.

## Details

I encountered the same problem today, and in my case, it turned out to be a copy-and-paste error!
On all our build-nodes we have startup script with this line

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://my-jenkins.com/computer/my-build-node-01/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret <secret for my-build-node-01>
```

I copied this startup script to the new build-node and only replaced the *secret*

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://my-jenkins.com/computer/my-build-node-01/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret <secret for my-build-node-02>
```

The URL was from build-node-01 and the secret was from build-node-02!

```
WRONG    java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://my-jenkins.com/computer/my-build-node-01/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret <secret for my-build-node-02>
CORRECT  java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://my-jenkins.com/computer/my-build-node-02/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret <secret for my-build-node-02>
```

### The error message

This was the whole error message if you mess up the `jnlpUrl` and the `secret`

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:263)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:342)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:122)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.loadDom(Launcher.java:604)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:546)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:346)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:297)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:702)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:373)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1913)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1779)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1817)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:158)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:861)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:247)
        ... 6 more
```